# Concatenate 2 rows in single rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, concatenation

i have this table with 2 rows

```
Id(PI,AI)    NAME     lNAME       country
1           fname1   lname1        USA
2           fname2   lname2        USA
```

how to concatenate  theses rows in single rows 
i want to use the result in php

```
Id        NAME                lNAME             Country
1 @ 2   fname1 @ fname2   lname1 @ lname1       USA @ USA
```

Separator = @
thanks

Comment: What's the Id field type? Is it auto increment?

Comment: Primary key and auto increment

Comment: Well, then you can't do it as far as I know. Auto increment fields are numeric, can't put spaces or @ symbols in there.

Comment: i want  to use this concatination in php not in mysql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `group_concat` function in combination with *subquery*:

```
SELECT 
    group_concat( Id separator ' @ ') as Id,
    group_concat( Name separator ' @ ') as Name,
    group_concat( lNAME separator ' @ ') as lNAME,
    group_concat( country separator ' @ ') as Country

FROM (SELECT * FROM table_name LIMIT 2) as t;
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat